# pecl installs to directory other than ext_dir

Tags: php, macos, pear, pecl

I have been plugging away, trying to install the pecl_http extension (it is a dependency for a library I am going to use). I am having an issue where the extension is being installed in the wrong directory.

I am working on an Apple MacBook Air, with OSX 10.8.5. I have the php that comes with OSX, and I have installed a more recent version (5.4.27) via Homebrew. I have configured my path to include the copy of php I installed via Homebrew.

My pecl configuration, and my php configuration, list the following as the extension_dir (ext_dir):

```
/usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525
```

However, the output from the `pecl install pecl_install` command tells me that the extension has been installed in the following location:

```
/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626
```

I have included the following output for reference:

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/http/php_http.h'
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/http/php_http_api.h'
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/http/php_http_buffer.h'
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/http/php_http_client.h'
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/http/php_http_client_request.h'
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/http/php_http_client_response.h'
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/http/php_http_cookie.h'
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/http/php_http_curl.h'
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/http/php_http_encoding.h'
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/http/php_http_env.h'
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/http/php_http_env_request.h'
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/http/php_http_env_response.h'
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/http/php_http_etag.h'
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/http/php_http_exception.h'
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/http/php_http_filter.h'
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/http/php_http_header.h'
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/http/php_http_header_parser.h'
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/http/php_http_info.h'
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/http/php_http_message.h'
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/http/php_http_message_body.h'
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/http/php_http_message_parser.h'
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/http/php_http_misc.h'
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/http/php_http_negotiate.h'
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/http/php_http_object.h'
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/http/php_http_options.h'
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/http/php_http_params.h'
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/http/php_http_querystring.h'
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/http/php_http_strlist.h'
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/http/php_http_url.h'
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/http/php_http_version.h'
Installing '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/http.so'
```

Additionally, I have configured pecl to use the php.ini file which is associated with the php I installed via Homebrew.

My questions are:

What would cause pecl to install in this directory (which I have not configured it to), and what can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

PEAR not using `ext_dir` is a bug; http://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=18666